# vertical slider on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am searching for a slider which should change the slides vertically on scroll.

This is the refrence Url : https://www.uber.com/ The Mobile slider

Please help me,i am trying to do this since7,8 hours.
this is the code i am trying to use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// var totalheight=$(window).height();
// $('.carosel-section').css('height',totalheight);

//Set each section's height equals to the window height
//$('.moveable').height($(window).height());

$('.moveable').first().addClass('active');

$('.carousel-wrap').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the default mousewheel scrolling
    var active = $('.moveable.active');
    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    if (delta < 0) {
        //mousewheel down handler
        next = active.next();
        if (next.length) {
            var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: next.offset().top
                }, 'fast');

                // move the indicator 'active' class
                next.addClass('active')
                    .siblings().removeClass('active');

                clearTimeout(timer);
            }, 100);
        }

    } else {
        prev = active.prev();

        if (prev.length) {
            var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: prev.offset().top
                }, 'slow');

                prev.addClass('active')
                    .siblings().removeClass('active');

                clearTimeout(timer);
            }, 800);
        }

    }
});

});
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? How do we execute provided code ?

Comment: Actually I just tried the code. It doesn't work. I added inline scroll to slides and then tried to achieve the one page scroll effect within the section.

Comment: Do you want the whole page to be able to slide vertically? Or just the parts of it like Uber?

Comment: Just the parts, there is a section which has 3 slides with content and image. I want to scroll those slides either horizontally or vertically when scroll reaches there and when the last slide is shown it should continue to scroll on page. The only issue I am having is my slides are not equal to widow height. All the jquery plugins/examples I tried shows the usage on full height sections.

Comment: This is the section from Uber : http://prntscr.com/ap8icn

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried looking at [Parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)? I think that is what you are looking for. The examples on the main page should give you a quick start!

Comment: This has to comment...!

Comment: @Rayon Dabre : Comments should be used only to suggest modification to the questions. My was an actual answer to the problem statement: "i am searching for a slider which should change the slides vertically on scroll"

Comment: Is it ? Op has a code snippet which _is not working_ How does your answer solves the purpose. And if OP is searching for something like that, it must be closed under _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers"_